# Regexp: return array of matches without dividing character

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to take a string with some special characters, and return an array of matches, but without the dividing characters, so the string

```
somebody@place&time[with,some,people]
```

will return

['somebody', 'place', 'time','with,some,people']

I currently have

```
(\w+)|(@\w+)|(&\w+)|\[([\w=\|,]+)\]
```

I can't just split on non-alphanumeric characters, because I want somebody to be able to provide

@place[with,some,people]

And the regex will return

[undefined, 'place', undefined,'width,some,people']

I'm pretty sure there is a way for me to remove the separation characters, but I can't seem to find it

--------------Update ----------------------------

As @CodeJockey mentioned, I didn't specify a language, because I thought this would be better as an open ended (as regexp works across multiple languages). I'm specifically using javascript and `string.match` to return an array of matches.

To answer @CodeJockey's other questions regarding the examples he provided

```
someone@area&time[] = ["someone","area","time",""]
@location = [undefined,"location",undefined, undefined]
@&tempus = [undefined, "","tempus",undefined]
@tempus?? = [undefined, "tempus??", undefined, undefined]
noone@nowhere&never[all,humans,that,ever,existed] = ["noone", "nowhere","ever","all,humans,that,ever,existed"]
savior@some undisclosed place&rapture:30[true,believers] = ["savoir","some",undefined, undefined] //as I have already cleaned the string so there are no spaces.
```

In the examples above, undefined or empty string don't really matter, either is acceptable as I need to be checking for that later.

Comment: You seem to say you want a regex-only solution, but then you say you want an array. Regexes don't have anything to do with arrays outside of the context of a programming language, which you don't specify. Such things are important in determining which regex features are available... please also clarify what can be variable length/number and optional things (i.e. what about `someone@area&time[]` or `@location` or `@&tempus` [or `@tempus`??] or `noone@nowhere&never[all,humans,that,ever,existed]` or `savior@some undisclosed place&rapture:30[true,believers]` n.b. the spaces...)

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be more flexible without specifying a language. I'll update the question.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I'm not sure if you're going to be able to get an array out of one statement with these requirements, but I'll give it some thought (I believe that JavaScript usually allows one to include a function that returns an array wherever you might otherwise include an array directly, and that might help); one further area of inquiry - what characters are allowed (and thus should be parsed as a complete token) within each "token" (like location/time/people, etc) - a time might contain `:` or `.`, or `-` characters or even others? you "clean" out spaces but what else?

Comment: thanks @CodeJockey, I just realized that the match method doesn't work as I thought it did. I wouldn't spend too much time thinking on this, I don't think. I fear I've sent people on a wild goose chase. I've just looked at the source for sizzle.js and how they break a jquery dom query into an object. I'm guessing if this were possible with one regexp, sizzle.js would have done it.

Comment: I'm nnot sure exactly what output you need, but I think I might have shown a way to provide it in an update to your fiddle (based upon @ghoti's answer). Please consider my answer below.

Comment: regex is a convenience, for the most part, allowing someone to break down validation or parsing "logic" into a series of characters, which can be provided, stored, and/or maintained in a single place (like a user or admin-maintained field on a page or in a database). It is not _efficient_. Sizzle requires the use of the most efficient methods, in order to be the basis for other frameworks and not bog things down. They probably don't use regex at all where possible, and only use it when the benefit of providing less source code outweighs the probable performance hit.

Comment: @CodeJockey, actually Sizzle does use regex, but they use a different regex for each item they are looking for. Check out the source at line 110. https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/dist/sizzle.js, Thanks for taking your time with the answer. I thought regexp was an efficient method, but maybe a split is better, I'll have to play with performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ php -r '$s="somebody@place&time[with,some,people]"; preg_match("/^([^@]*)@([^&]+)&([^[]+)[[]([^]]+)[]]/", $s, $a); unset($a[0]); print_r($a);'
Array
(
    [1] => somebody
    [2] => place
    [3] => time
    [4] => with,some,people
)
```

Note that the regex's first element expands with `*` instead of `+`, to allow for empty "somebody" strings per your question.  Also note that an empty string is merely empty, not undefined.

Comment: Thanks Ghoti, but I'm almost positive there is a way for me to do this within the regexp, and not do any 'post processing' as you've laid out here.

Comment: Removed post-processing.  This output looks like it matches the example output in your question.

Comment: You'll see on this jsfiddle, the regexp you've provided returns null. :( http://jsfiddle.net/7uybX/

Comment: @pedalpete - I am not a JS developer, and I can't itemize its regex failings for you.  The regex works when used in PHP.  http://codepad.viper-7.com/9tKau9

Comment: Thanks. That's interesting, I thought regexp implementation was common across languages. Thanks

Comment: JavaScript regex implementation, for one, does not support lookbehinds of any sort, but it might come down to the way you formatted the regex and the different requirements for how JavaScript takes regex input, etc. - I'd have to take a closer look

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this may help somebody else. I thought I could do this with regexp using the match method in javascript, but I think I'm wrong.

I now think the correct way of doing this is the way sizzle.js (the DOM query engine for jQuery) does it. You can find it here.
https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/dist/sizzle.js,
look for the `matchExpr` around line 110.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fiddle you referenced in response to @ghoti, [I modified and fixed the expression he suggested](http://jsfiddle.net/7uybX/2/):

```
var to_parse = "name@place&time[with,other,people]";

var parse_array = to_parse.match(/^([^@]*)@([^&]+)&([^[]+)\[([^\]]+)\]/);
```

EITHER of the following statements remove the "entire match" element from index 0 and place the result in the parse_array variable, but only the first statement is chainable...

```
parse_array = parse_array.splice(1,4);
parse_array.splice(0,1);
```

a single statement version of the above is this:

```
var parse_array = to_parse.match(/^([^@]*)@([^&]+)&([^[]+)\[([^\]]+)\]/).splice(1,4);
```

to output the result nicely (by emphasizing the difference between the commas separating the array items and the commas separating the items contained within the string of the last item) to the console, use:

```
console.log('[\"' + parse_array.join("\", \"") + '\"]');
```

hope this helps you